# How to manipulate certain columns into rows

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
Id | Name | year | Offer1 | Offer2 | Offer3
1    Joe    2019   Army    Navy     UGA
2    Sally  2019   UA      UVA      UF
```

Is there any code in R or VBA that would transpose the dataset to look like this:

```
Id | Name | year | Offer
1    Joe    2019   Army
1    Joe    2019   Navy
1    Joe    2019   UGA
2    Sally  2019   UA
2    Sally  2019  UVA
2    Sally  2019   UF
```

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = starts_with('Offer'))`

Comment: `data.table::melt(data.table::setDT(df),measure.vars = patterns("Offer"),value.name = "Offer")`